# Contradicting solutions in a probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

The following problem appears at *Mathematical Statistics*:

[image: Untitled]

I found two solutions, both of which seem reasonable to me, but which lead to different results. Clearly at least one of them is wrong, but I can not see why. I will reproduce them below.

---

$\text{Solution 1 : }$

This solution is the simplest. Let $C$ be the event of no contamination, $A$ and $B$ the events of homonymous contamination. Then

$$P(C) =0.2 \implies P(A \cup B\big) = 0.8$$

We know $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$. Then

$$P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B)=0.8 \iff 0.5+0.4-P(A\cap B)=0.8 \\ \rightarrow P(A\cap B)=0.1$$

It is clear $P(A \cap B)$ is the case where the sample has $2$ contaminations. Then $P(C)=0.2, P(A \cap B)=0.1$ can be expressed for $Y$ as $P(Y=0)=0.2, P(Y=2)=0.1$, from which follows necessarily that $P(Y=1)=0.7$.

*Final answer:* The distribution $f$ of $Y$ can be described as

$$
f(y)=\begin{cases} 
      0.2 & y = 0 \\
      0.7 & y=1 \\
      0.1 & y= 2 
   \end{cases}
$$

$\text{Solution 2 :}$

The possibilities are $y=0, y=1, y=2$. We know $P(Y=0)=0.2$ and the question is about the overlap of the remaining two possibilities. Notice that

$$
P(Y\neq0)=0.8 \implies P(Y=1 \cup Y=2\big) = 0.8
$$

From this follows $P(Y=1)+ P(Y=2)=0.8$, since they are mutually exclusive (we can not have one and two types of contamination).

Notice that $P(Y=2)= P(A \cap B)$, where $A$ is the event for type $A$ contamination and $B$ the event for type $B$  contamination. Because they are independent, we have

$$
P(Y=2)= P(A \cap B)=0.5(0.4)=0.2 \tag{Probably the error?}
$$

Then from the fact that $P(Y=1)+ P(Y=2)=0.8$ it follows $P(Y=2)=0.8-0.2 = 0.6$ and then

$$
f(y)=\begin{cases} 
      0.2 & y = 0 \\
      0.6 & y=1 \\
      0.2 & y= 2 
   \end{cases}
$$

is the distribution of $Y$.

---

As you can see, both answers differ in their computations of $P(Y=2)$. One starts with the probabilities of the contaminations, and uses the fact that $P(A \cup B) = 0.8$ to infer $P(A \cap B)$, from which $P(Y = 2)=0.1$ follows.

The other directly states $P(Y = 2) = P(A) \times P(B)=0.2$ (since $y = 2$ can only happen if $A$ and $B$ both occurr, and they are independent).

I would appreciate it if someone could point out my error/s. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that the presence of $A$ and/or $B$ are independent events.  Indeed, making that assumption leads to a contradiction (as you have discovered).

Comment: Thank you @lulu!

Comment: Your solution 1 is the one intended by the book and makes sense of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct is correct, you can't assume $A$ and $B$ are independent.

From the first solution:

$$0.1 = P(A\cap B) \neq P(A)P(B) = (0.4)(0.5) = 0.2.$$

Comment: Thank you! That explains it all.